# How to create a remote filter on multiple fields? Ext Js 5

Tags: extjs, extjs5

How can I create a filter on multiple fields, which filters on the server, and not in the local store?

So far I've only gotten locally.

```
onFilter: function(field, newValue, oldValue, options){
    var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid');
    grid.store.clearFilter();

    if (newValue) {
        var matcher = new RegExp(Ext.String.escapeRegex(newValue), "i");
        grid.store.filter({
            filterFn: function(record) {
                return matcher.test(record.get('id')) ||
                    matcher.test(record.get('names'));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set filters with filterFn on remote filtering. Remote filtering can only take property-value-operator combinations that are sent to the backend, and have to be evaluated and acted on by the backend.

To filter on multiple properties, you can of course send multiple filters to the backend:

```
store.addFilters([{
    id: 'idFilter',
    property: 'id',
    operator: 'eq',
    value: newValue
},{
    id: 'nameFilter',
    property: 'names',
    operator: 'like',
    value: newValue
}]);
```

The backend then has to evaluate and apply these filters to the data. The values are sent to the backend without client-side validation or usage, so you could even send arbitrary property or operator names to the backend:

```
store.addFilters([{
    id: 'idOrNameFilter',
    property: 'idOrName',
    operator: 'somethingsomething',
    value: newValue
}]);
```

You would just have to tell your backend to parse the property name correctly from the parameter string and act accordingly.